# Railscast image cropper broken in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is the walkthrough I followed, which was working:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images

Here is the error I'm receiving after upgrading to Rails 4

```
Started PATCH "/crop" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-13 14:37:02 -0500
Processing by UsersController#crop as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"aTVhNXWWs6nyDnFbbqqHaKS90QafxVlLp4nGs8J4a8E=", "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000002146c28 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140713-29032-2bjf1p>, @original_filename="74926649.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"74926649.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Crop Uploaded Image"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` = 188  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/7492664920140713-29032-1guokao.jpg[0]'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 72ms

NameError - undefined local variable or method `crop_x' for #<User:0x00000002274a50>:
```

The line which triggers the error is:

```
  def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
  end
```

Comment: Can you post the line which is the culprit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `crop_x' for #<User:0x00000002274a50>:
```

It means the variable `crop_x` does not exist. Make sure you followed the tutorial and defined the attribute accessor at the top of your model.

Comment: Since this is Rails 4, I have added :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h to my strong parameters in the Users Controller

Comment: Strong parameters has nothing to do with `attr_accessor`, you are probably confusing `attr_accessor` with `attr_protected`.

Comment: Oh wow. Sorry about that. I was really confused. Sorry it's my first day on Rails 4